# AWS ECR endpoint no_proxy issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, proxy, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

I have been working on `ECR`.

I created an endpoint to be able to pull and push `docker` container without leaving the VPC.

My problem is that I am behind a proxy

My `http-proxy.conf` looks like this

```
[Service]
Environment= "http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:8080"
Environment= "https_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:8080"
Environment= "no_proxy=.dkr.ecr.us-west2.amazonaws.com"
```

For some reason when I do a `docker pull` from one of my containers inside `ECR` it is really slow because it's using the `proxy` instead of `non-proxy`.

If I remove the first 2 line `http` and `https` its is really fast.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after a couple of days, I found the issue; I had to add the s3 endpoint to the no_proxy. It looks like when I did a docker pull because the s3 was not reachable, it went outside the network and back in. Now I am able to pull images within the VPC!!

```
[Service]
Environment= "http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:8080"
Environment= "https_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:8080"
Environment= "no_proxy=.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com,.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `noProxy` for any specific URL with `*`

As per [`docker` man](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client):

> [Configure Docker to use a proxy server | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client)
>
> - On the Docker client, create or edit the file `~/.docker/config.json` in the home directory of the user which starts containers. Add JSON such as the following, substituting the type of proxy with `httpsProxy` or `ftpProxy` if necessary, and substituting the address and port of the proxy server. You can configure multiple proxy servers at the same time.
>
>   You can optionally exclude hosts or ranges from going through the proxy server by setting a `noProxy` key to one or more comma-separated IP addresses or hosts. Using the `*` character as a wildcard is supported, as shown in this example.
>
>   ```
>   {
>    "proxies":
>    {
>      "default":
>      {
>        "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
>        "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
>        "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
>      }
>    }
>   }
>   ```
>
>   Save the file.
> - When you create or start new containers, the environment variables are set automatically within the container.

Comment: I just want to pull the containers that I have in ECR.. docker pull dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/whaever:latest to go via no_proxy, I tried adding ~/.docker/config.json but it does not work

Comment: Hi. Have you created *new* containers after edit `config.json` ?